# Textarea in chrome gets clipped

Tags: html, google-chrome, xslt, cross-browser

I have the following issue, I have an XSL which converts an XML to an HTML file. The part is below is causing the issue:

```
<td>
 <textarea style="width:100%; border:0px solid #000;overflow:hidden;height:100%" readonly="yes" scroll="no">
   <xsl:value-of select="$GLBL_TRNS_CMNT" />
 </textarea>
</td>
```

The length of the text in `$GLBL_TRNS_CMNT` varies quite a bit. I need the `<textarea>` to fit based on the length of the text. This works fine in IE, however in Chrome the text gets cut off and I only see the first 2 lines. If I manually change the height to `500px`, then I can see the cut off part. Can anyone tell me hwo to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textareas do not automatigically resize with the content. What is more, you have `overflow:hidden`, which means that any part not fitting should be made invisible. Chrome is behaving as it should, IE is not.

You cannot fix this with just HTML and CSS (let alone XSLT, which runs *before* the box is rendered, so it is little use here for resizing it, as it does not know the height and width of the glyphs of the font you are using).

One way to solve this is by creating an invisible `div` element which resizes automatically, and to set that height to the height of your textbox. How to do this is explained in several blog entries, but [this one on ImpressiveWebs, about auto-sizing a textbox to its content](http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/), is very clear and easy to copy and paste into your situation.

Comment: For some reason, my employer only uses pure Javascript, so the link below worked better, but your comment pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! http://chuvash.eu/2011/12/14/the-cleanest-auto-resize-for-a-textarea/